# How to create KJar locally without using business central kie containers

Tags: drools, redhat, drools-kie-server, redhat-brms, redhat-bpm

Do we have any documentation / suggestion available on how to generate/build Redhat Drools rules Kjar locally without using Business Central Kie-Containers ?

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To build kjars locally, use the kie-maven-plugin

See https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_buildingwithmaven

Comment: Eleven years later, Page not found.  Maybe something on this page helps: https://blog.kie.org/2021/11/drools-basic-examples.html

Comment: @MartinThurn what do you mean? Question is from 2020 and the URL is still working. I updated it with latest nevertheless

Comment: Oh hmmm sorry maybe it was a temporary glitch when I clicked it.  Thanks for the update!